# Magento 2 : How to override translation file module wise?

Tags: magento2, localisation, translate

I need to update translation file only for checkout page , so how can I do that . I don't want to use translation file which is use in theme folder.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the module name as Vendor_Module in front of the phrase and its translation in the csv.

Answer (score 0):

In your csv file, you should write **for module**:

**"Original phrase","Translation",module,Vendor_Module**

**don't change** "module". just phrases and Vendor_Module. "module" here, as you understand, shows for magento where translation must be applied

**PS:** if you want to use translation **for theme**, you can do this:

**"Original phrase","Translation",theme,frontend/Magento/luma**

where frontend/Magento/luma - path to theme

Comment: its not working , i have use csv as below,
Order Total,Grand Total:,module,Magento_Checkout
this changes is also applied on order history page

Comment: i haven't check this, but i have an idea. Not sure, that it is good way...

Try to override template, which displays this part with "Order Total". Then in your module in csv file:

"Order Total","Grand Total:",module,Vendor_Module

This translation will applied only for this phrase in your module, and it will not applied to history page. Please, let me know, is it helps or not. THX.